# Cosine distance range interpretation

Tags: matlab, distance

I am trying to use the cosine distance in `pdist2`. I am confused about it's output. As far as I know it should be between 0 and 1. Since MATLAB uses 1-(cosine), then 1 would be the highest variability while 0 would be the lowest. However the output seems to range from 0.5 to 1.5 or something along that!

Can somebody please advise me on how to interpret this output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `help pdist2`:

> 'cosine'      - One minus the cosine of the included angle
>                   between observations (treated as vectors)

Since the cosine varies between -1 and 1, the result of `pdist2(...'cosine')` varies between 0 and 2. If you want the cosine, use `1-pdist2(matrix1,matrix2,'cosine')`.

Comment: Thank you. Now, let's say I get the cosine distance, what result would mean the closest distance and what would mean the most variable ? Based on my interpretation, when I get 1 then it is the closest and -1 is furthest. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Louis I guess so. But just try with a few vectors and see what comes out of `pdist2`